# How to include the DependencyInjection scope in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging with multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, dependency-injection

I do a `Task.Run()` and inside of it I create a scope for dependency injection (`using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())`).  I would like to inform the loggerfactory and loggers about that scope and then prepend it to the logs.

After looking at the source, I saw that the loggerfactory and logger<> are singleton which makes it hard for use in the way I am trying to.  If I change it in one thread, it will change for all other threads...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using SeriLog and it is possible to achieve what I wanted with enrichment.  At Serilog setup, you need to ensure that you setup enrichment for LogContext:

```
return webHost
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseSerilog((context, config) =>
    {
        config
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext();
    });
```

and then add the scope information you want just before or after creating your DI scope:

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    using (Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("ExecutionScope", "MyMultithreadedScope "))
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
    {
        Logger.LogDebug("test");
        //....
    }
});
```

You also need to specify your property in Serilog outputTemplate. Ex: `"{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {ExecutionScope}{Message}"`

LogContext uses [AsyncLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netcore-2.2) to keep the information in the context and it supports control flow changes like async and multithreading.